# SPSS can't assign string variable

Tags: string, spss

The first block of code runs fine but i where it says "value of F14a" i want it to actually assign the string that is stored there to F14a_pd3. But the Syntax below that should do that crashes SPSS for me. F14a is a string variable of length 50.

Working useless Syntax:

```
STRING F14a_pd3 (A50).
DO IF NOT F14a="missing" & papadex=3.
   COMPUTE F14a_pd3="value of F14a".
ELSE.
   COMPUTE F14a_pd3="missing".
END IF.
FREQUENCIES F14a_pd3.
```

Crashing Syntax:

```
STRING F14a_pd3 (A50).
DO IF NOT F14a="missing" & papadex=3.
   COMPUTE F14a_pd3=F14a.
ELSE.
   COMPUTE F14a_pd3="missing".
END IF.
FREQUENCIES F14a_pd3.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider calling technical support. Your syntax is fine, and even if it wasn't it shouldn't make anything crash (at worst you should just get an error message).

Run this reproducible example demonstrating your syntax. If this doesn't "crash" SPSS, then it is possibly a problem with the current file you are working on.

```
data list free / F14a (A10) papadex (F1.0).
begin data
missing 3
xxxxx  3
missing 0
yyyyy 1
zzzzz 0
end data.

STRING F14a_pd3 (A10).
DO IF NOT F14a="missing" & papadex=3.
   COMPUTE F14a_pd3=F14a.
ELSE.
   COMPUTE F14a_pd3="missing".
END IF.
LIST ALL.
```

Which produces the table;

> ```
> F14a       papadex F14a_pd3 
>
> missing       3    missing 
> xxxxx         3    xxxxx 
> missing       0    missing 
> yyyyy         1    missing 
> zzzzz         0    missing
> ```

Answer (score 1):

That syntax works fine for me.  When you say SPSS crashes, exactly what happens?  And what else is going on in that session?  What version and platform are you using?